# How to increase the accuracy of the keras model and prevent overfitting

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to train

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation='relu', input_shape=(x1, x2, depth)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Here's how I'm compiling it:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=0.0, momentum=0.05, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've tried various learning rates and different optimizers. But the accuracy doesn't seem to go beyond 50% as shown below:
[image]

My images are properly normalized around 0 with STD as 1.

Is there something I am missing? How can I improve the accuracy of the model?

**EDIT:**

Hey, when I use the following data generator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True)



train_generator = train_datagen.flow(np.array(X_train), batch_size=batchsize)
valid_generator = test_datagen.flow(np.array(X_test), batch_size = batchsize)

history = model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(np.array(X_train), y_train_cat, batch_size=batchsize),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // batchsize, epochs=epochs, 
                    validation_data= valid_generator, 
                    validation_steps=len(X_test) // batchsize)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I used to solve this by either updating `numpy` or uninstalling it and installing it again, but this time, it's not working with either. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Machine learning, and specifically hyperparameter tuning, is an extremely complex topic. In order for us (the community) to provide you helpful tips, we would require a lot more information regarding the task you're trying to perform; the training/test data you are currently using; what specific optimizers and learning rates (or other parameters) you have tried. The more specific information you provide, the higher the chance of getting a useful respones!

Comment: I would suggest you 1. use `he_normal` (or `he_uniform` instead of `random_uniform`) 2. obtain close to 100% accuracy on train set and then add dropout, regularization step-by-step. I think you have added too much dropout, especially after the first stage. Remember, when you do `max-pool`, `dropout`, `regularization` etc. you are introducing some kind of noise into your network, which indeed is useful to avoid overfitting. However, too much noise can prevent you from learning, especially with small data.

Comment: @dennlinger, I edited my question to clarify a few things. I've tried `SGD`, `adagrad`, `adam` optimizers but none are giving any decent outputs. I have tried LR as `0.1, 0.5, 0.05, 0.01`, but no change.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, thanks. I tried to remove the `dropout` layer and even reduced the LR to `0.01` and `0.05`. There seems to be an increase in accuracy to 60% but now it's overfitting there.

Comment: You are augmenting the testing data, you shouldn't be doing that. Its a big no no.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, it's just named `test`. It's actually the `validation set`. I got the idea from [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) link.

Comment: The same applies for validation data, it should not be augmented.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, okay. Let me try.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Just to be clear, you mean that one doesn't need to do `rotation` or `flip` augmentation. Because, mean and std normalization is still required for the test data, but the normalization factors should be derived from the training data.

Comment: Yes, rotation or flips are augmentations, and you should not do augmentations. Normalization is fine.

Comment: So instead of augmentation like training set, I should just normalize the validation set?

Also, one weird thing. This model was working like two weeks back. I used the same for the same purpose and suddenly, the only thing I did was to add some new images, it stopped working. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: As I said before, use the train set normalization factors to normalize your test set. Secondly, I assume the new images are similar to your train set. If not, I could see why your network fails to work.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, yes. The new image are very similar to the training set.

Answer (score 0):

You have already captured things like tweaking learning rates, dropouts, batchnormalization etc - which is a good starting point to tweak.

Have you tried regularization?

Check out
https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/neural-networks-tuning-techniques/index.html

If it doesnt help, you might need to look at how the input is structured and see if there are other ways that more helpful for the network to converge.  This includes making sure that train and validation has same level of variance in data etc.  This is however, more domain specific to what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hey. I think adding `dropout` layer is a form of `regularization`. So I have done that. I've also done some data generation in case my data size was the problem. What do you suggest?